# Como redirecionar url com htaccess para fora do domínio?

Tags: htaccess, link, domínio

Possuo um domínio `www.dominio.com.br`.

Em determinada página, preciso colocar um link para o google+ do cliente. Estou usando:

```
a href="www.google.com" target="_blank"
```

Para testes, e o que esta ocorrendo é que invés de o sistema abrir uma nova aba com o endereço `www.google.com` ele esta tentando redirecionar para dentro do meu domínio (`www.dominio.com.br/www.google.com`)

Alguém sabe como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas modifique sua propriedade `href` para `href="http://www.google.com"`

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

amigo, você vai direcionar apenas uma página? Não seria mais simples usar um redirecionamento via PHP, por exemplo?

```
<?php header("Location: http://www.site_a_ser_redirecionado.com"); ?>
```

Comment: Até pode ser, porém achei que era mais simples fazer pela tag a href ja que era um link simples mesmo

Answer (score 0):

Oi, tenta assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?$ http\:\/\/plus\.google\.com\/+Coca-Cola\/
```

Obs.: Traque a URL escapando sempre com uma barra invertida (\) os ":", ".", "/"

Comment: Ah, é um link? Você esqueceu de colocar o "http://" antes do www.

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Você não precisa utilizar nenhuma linguagem *server-side* para isso, basta adicionar o protocolo `http` ou `https` antes:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
```

Muitas vezes ocorre erro de autenticação SSL por não utilizar o protocolo correto, então você pode omitir o protocolo e adicionar apenas `//`, deixando que o servidor se encarregue de redirecionar para o protocolo correto:

```
<a href="//www.google.com" target="_blank">
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado.

Comment: @VictorGazotti que bom, se a resposta lhe foi útil marque ela como aceita, para indicar que a questão foi encerrada. Se você achar que merece dê também um voto a favor. ;)

Comment: Obrigado, infelizmente não consigo votar a favor pois não tenho reputação para isso =/ desculpe